# Vertical text on a Gnome2::Canvas (Perl/Gtk2)

Tags: perl, canvas, gtk2

Drawing on a Gnome2::Canvas, I want to draw X and Y axes, with a horizontal label and a vertical label.

Gnome2::Canvas::Text objects allow Pango markup. A Pango tag like this should work, but doesn't.

```
<span gravity="west">...</span>
```

Is there any way to overcome Gtk's reluctance to draw rotated text?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package vertical;

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;

use Gtk2 '-init';
use Gnome2::Canvas;

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->set_title('Hello world');
$window->set_position('center');
$window->set_default_size(500, 500);
$window->signal_connect('delete-event' => sub {

    Gtk2->main_quit();
    exit;
});

my $canvasFrame = Gtk2::Frame->new(undef);
$window->add($canvasFrame);
$canvasFrame->set_border_width(3);

my $canvasScroller = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new();
$canvasFrame->add($canvasScroller);
$canvasScroller->set_border_width(3);
$canvasScroller->set_policy('always','always');

my $canvas = Gnome2::Canvas->new();
$canvasScroller->add($canvas);
$canvas->set_scroll_region(0, 0, 400, 400);
$canvas->set_center_scroll_region(1);

# White background
my $canvasObj = Gnome2::Canvas::Item->new (
    $canvas->root(),
    'Gnome2::Canvas::Rect',
    x1 => 0,
    y1 => 0,
    x2 => 400,
    y2 => 400,
    fill_color => '#FFFFFF',
    outline_color => '#FFFFFF',
);
$canvasObj->lower_to_bottom();

# Black text
my $canvasObj2 = Gnome2::Canvas::Item->new(
    $canvas->root(),
    'Gnome2::Canvas::Text',
    x => 100,
    y => 300,
    fill_color => '#000000',
    font => 'Sans',
    size => 20000,
    anchor => 'GTK_ANCHOR_W',
    markup => "this is <span gravity=\"east\">not vertical</span>",
);
$canvasObj2->raise_to_top();

$window->show_all();

Gtk2->main();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of the `gravity` attribute in the Pango markup is not supported, at least I was not able to make it work.

However, instead of using `Gnome2::Canvas`, you could try using the `rotate()` function in `Cairo::Context`. Here is an example using `Gtk3`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk3 '-init';
use Glib qw/TRUE FALSE/;
use Cairo;
use Pango;

use constant PI     => 3.1415927;

my $window = Gtk3::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->set_title("Cairo Basics");
$window->set_position("mouse");
$window->set_default_size(600, 400);
$window->set_border_width(5);
$window->signal_connect (delete_event => sub { Gtk3->main_quit });

my $frame = Gtk3::Frame->new("Cairo Drawings");
$window->add($frame);
my $drawable = Gtk3::DrawingArea->new;
$drawable->signal_connect( draw => sub { cairo_draw($drawable, @_ ) });
$frame->add($drawable);
$window->show_all;
Gtk3->main;

sub cairo_draw {
    my ( $drawable, $widget, $context, $ref_status ) = @_;

    my $pango_layout = $drawable->create_pango_layout("");
    $pango_layout->set_markup(
        "<span foreground = '#FF4444'"
        ." size = '20000' face='sans' style='normal' weight='bold'>"
        . "This is vertical</span>"
    );
    my $pango_context = $pango_layout->get_context();
    $context->move_to(200, 100);
    $context->rotate(PI*(90/180));
    Pango::Cairo::show_layout( $context, $pango_layout );    
    return FALSE;
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can skip the Pango markup altogether and only use Cairo:

```
sub cairo_draw {
    my ( $drawable, $widget, $context, $ref_status ) = @_;

    $context->set_source_rgba(1, 0.4, 0.4, 1);
    $context->select_font_face( "Sans", "normal", "bold" );
    $context->set_font_size( 35 );
    $context->move_to(220, 50);
    $context->rotate(PI*(90/180));
    $context->show_text( "This is vertical");
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Alas, using Cairo instead of Gnome2::Canvas is not an option.

Comment: I really think you should consider trying to upgrade your app to Gtk3 and Cairo. According to [the Perl GTK project page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK-Perl), `Gnome2::Canvas` is considered deprecated which is also [confirmed](https://developer.gnome.org/libgnomecanvas/) by its backend library's (`libgnomecanvas`) home page. The transistion from GTK2 to GTK3 was done 8 years ago, and in that process `libgnomecanvas` was deprecated in favor of `libcairo`, see [this discussion](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2009/04/msg00002.html) for more information

Comment: I would be happy to upgrade to Gtk3. But it appears to be impossible to install gtk2-perl on MS Windows. The Win32 binaries available ten years ago are either missing or broken. The Sisyphusion repository contains some working binaries, but they only work with Gtk2, not Gtk3.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem you have... I am not using Windows, so I'm sorry I cannot give good advice here. Have you tried [this](https://github.com/MaxPerl/perl-Gtk3-windows-installer) Gtk3 installer for Window?